# I want to fit a curve to my data and perform 1st and 2nd order derivative. How do I do it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data set is like this:

```
type <- rep(c("a", "b"), each=7)
con <- rep(c(32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0), 2)
Abs_net <-  c(0.06, 0.142, 0.231, 0.504, 1.648, 1.759, 1.525, 0.063, 0.091,0.115, 0.117, 0.118, 0.881, 1.515)
data <- data.frame(con, Abs_net, type)
```

I tried this code

```
ggplot(data, aes(con, Abs_net, color=type)) +
geom_point()+
geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

I also tried span inside `geom_smooth` however, it does not help.

I want to see the non linear graph such that Abs_net  only decreases at higher values of con and only increases at lower value of con (I do not want increasing and decreasing patterns). I can get it in graph pad prism but not in R.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible fit, assuming a model of the form y = e^-x

```
ggplot(data, aes(con, Abs_net, color=type)) +
  geom_point(size = 2)+
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", 
              formula = y ~ exp(-x),
              se=FALSE, lty = "dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: I think I like that answer more than mine

Comment: thank you. But formula = y ~ exp(-x) does not work as you see for type a. Nor does the formula y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE)) is working. My problem is I donot know the formula for it (may be it does not have fixed formula.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. You wrote "Abs_net only decreases at higher values of con and only increases at lower value of con (I do not want increasing and decreasing patterns)", which to me sounds like you want a function that is **monotonically decreasing**. But your data for A is increasing from 1.5 to 1.7 between 0 and 1, so I'm not sure how that should work. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. theoretically it should be either increasing only or decreasing only, however, practically I get data as above. I want the curve to resemble the theoretical data.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it took me quite some time to understand your question, but I think I did understand it in the end.
The issue seems to be that even though the Abs_net are decreasing monotonely in "con" the plot doesn't do so.

To fix that you can:
- Use a different smoothing function

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(con, Abs_net, color=type)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE, method = "loess", formula = y~x)
```

(here method = can be replaced by for example "lm" (which I assume is not what you actually want, but something closer)

You will have to look around for other methods, I couldn't find one that solves your problem.

Something like

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(con, Abs_net, color=type)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE, method = "glm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE))
```

looks better but still has the issue (doesn't hit the data points exactly and slopes up in the end).

Please also note that under https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html you can see what functions you can use for the method argument. You can also update the formulas loess uses (and indicated in my geom_smooth). Let me know if that helped.